# How do I transpose a row to a column in a tab-delimited file?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a tab-delimited file with a number and the names belonging to the same number on the same row. The number and names are separated by a tab. The names are linked with each other by 2 underscores (`__`). It looks like this:

```
33  Hhe.1__Hhe.2__Hhe.3__Hhe.4
```

I would like to convert it (by using the command line) to this output:

```
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

Comment: there's also `man col` but it wouldn't duplicate the first number. Related though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F '\t|__' '{for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s\t%s\n", $1, $i}}' foo.txt 
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

- We split the lines into fields based on tab (`\t`) or two underscores (`__`).
- Then we loop over fields from the second till the last, and print each prefixed with the first field and a tab.

Comment: Was going to submit almost the same, just a stylistic difference in the loop: `{ for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1 "\t" $i }`

Answer (score 4):

You can use a perl one-liner for that:

```
perl -ane '@l=split(/__/,$F[1]); foreach $val (@l){print $F[0],"\t",$val,"\n"}'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "33  Hhe.1__Hhe.2__Hhe.3__Hhe.4" | perl -ane '@l=split(/__/,$F[1]); foreach $val (@l){print $F[0],"\t",$val,"\n"}'
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

Explanation of the commands used:

```
perl -ane                    #read input line-wise and split line on tab
'@l=split(/__/,$F[1]);       #split the second element ($F[1]) on a double _
foreach $val (@l){           #for each value, print the first element and the value.
  print $F[0],"\t",$val,"\n"
 }'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way using Perl:

```bsh
perl -lane '$,="\n"; print(map($F[0] . "\t" . $_, split("__", $F[1])))' file
```

```bsh
perl -lane '
    $,="\n";
    print(map($F[0] . "\t" . $_, split("__", $F[1])))
' file
```

- `-l[octnum]`: enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps `$/` (the input record separator) when used with `-n` or `-p`. Second, it assigns `$\` (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on. If octnum is omitted, sets `$\` to the current value of `$/`.
- `-a`: turns on autosplit mode when used with a `-n` or `-p`. An implicit split command to the `@F` array is done as the first thing inside the implicit while loop produced by the `-n` or `-p`.
- `-n`: causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`:

  ```perl
  LINE:
    while (<>) {
        ...             # your program goes here
    }
  ```
- `-e`: may be used to enter one line of program;
- `$,="\n"; print(map($F[0] . "\t" . $_, split("__", $F[1])))`; sets the output field separator to a newline character, splits the second field on `__` and prepends the first field followed by a tabulation to each subfield, finally printing the record.

```
% cat file
33  Hhe.1__Hhe.2__Hhe.3__Hhe.4
% perl -lane '$,="\n"; print(map($F[0] . "\t" . $_, split("__", $F[1])))' file
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another perl one-liner:

```
$ perl -lane 'print "$F[0]\t$_" for split(/__/,$F[1])' file 
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

This is the same basic idea as the existing Perl answers, only shorter. The `-a` automatically splits each line of the input file on whitespaces and makes the resulting fields available as the array `@F`. So, `$F[0]` is the 1st field, `$F[1]` the second and so on. The `-n` means "read each input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e`. The `-l` removes trailing `\n` characters from each input line and adds a `\n` to each `print` call.

`split(/__/,$F[1])` creates an array by splitting the 1st field of the file on the characters `__`. So, `print "$F[0]\t$_" for split...` will iterate over the array returned by the `split` call and print the first field of the file (`$F[0]`), a tab character `\t` and the current field of the `split` array.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what muru suggested: what about splitting the second field based on `__` and then looping through the slices?

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}
     {n=split($2,a,"__"); for (i=1;i<=n;i++) print $1, a[i]}' file
```

This uses the fact that [`split()`](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html) returns the number of elements created.

Also, it sets the Input and Output Field Separators to the tab, so that you then don't have to mention it when you `print`. In fact, `FS` doesn't need to be set here, because `FS` defaults to the space and tab is included.

It returns:

```
33  Hhe.1
33  Hhe.2
33  Hhe.3
33  Hhe.4
```

Comment: This is better than `for (i in a)`, since this will retain the original order, where `i in a` would result in random order.

Comment: Exactly! [Why does awk seem to randomize the array?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20683474/1983854).